# How to bind spark scala DataFrame to sparkR in zeppelin?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

created a dataframe in `spark`, trying to pass it to `spark.r`

Creating the binding the successfully created DataFrame to `z`:

```
%spark
z.put("myDF", myDF)
```

and from spark.r failing to get it:

```
%spark.r
z.get("myDF")
```

where I get

```
<simpleError in eval(expr, envir, enclos): could not find function "z.get">
```

How can I get the `DF` created in `spark` inside `spark.r`?

Comment: What repo of zeppelin are you using ? the official zeppelin repo still doesn't support the r-interpreter. There is a pull request hanging for a while now. I'm not even sure that this [repo](https://github.com/elbamos/Zeppelin-With-R/tree/rinterpreter) supports binding neither.

Comment: using the standard repo with `-Pr`

Comment: Ok. Can you try the following : `.z.get(...)` with a `.` before the `z` for the r interpreter ? normally this should work

Comment: Tell me if it works so I can write an answer

Comment: @eliasah yes it worked thanks.  can you please also add to answer how can I then access this df because I then tried `printSchema(.z.get(...))` and got error: `<simpleError in (function (classes, fdef, mtable) {...`

Comment: have you tried separating .z.get(...) and printSchema ? I would suggest to affect the result of .z.get to a df e.g df <- .z.get(...) then using printSchema

Comment: @eliasah yes same error.. you can post your answer i'll ask in another thread.  when I just issue `myDF` from the `%spark.r` it shows me its a `Java ref type org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame id 12` not sure if that's ok or not looks ok to me because its a reference to DataFrame shouldn't i convert it to `r` DF or something like that? (just guessing)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110052/discussion-between-eliasah-and-jas).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usage of the `ZeppelinContext` is a bit different with the `sparkr` interpreter :

You'll need to use the `.z.get(...)` with a `.` before the z for the `sparkr` interpreter. e.g :

```
%spark.r
.z.get("myDF")
```